# Некорректно отображается сайт в Mozilla

Tags: opencart

В общем есть сайт на opencart http://gav-yam.ru/ В хроме нормально отображается, в мозиле и edge все едет. Я так понимаю, что почему-то не подключаются css и js...

Comment: Одинаково едет в Firefox 59, Chrome 64, IE 11

Comment: Запорол несколько файлов и решил перенести все из admin, system и catalog по-новой. Файлы там все на месте, тем более что в хроме все работает. В ftp ошибок о передаче нет, так что все точно загрузилось. Буду очень благодарен за помощь :-)

Comment: А в чем может быть тогда проблема? в Хроме 63 версии не едет вроде как

Comment: @user283101 не может оно работать в 63 версии, у вас минимум в `.camera_caption` стоит `display:none;`, слайды почему-то абсолютно позиционированы, у родителя стоит огромный паддинг, зачем? Остальное даже не смотрел.

Comment: Да, кэш в хроме почистил, вылезло то же и самое. Сайт не я делал :-) В любом случае некоторые модули просто не хотят грузиться В консоли есть ошибки http://prntscr.com/i7hef8